# Kivy Python very basic Binding of Label Text

Tags: python, binding, label, kivy

I know this might be a very basic question, but after spending hours wrapping my head around it I still can't figure it out.

I basically just want to bind the text of a label to a variable in the python code. lets call it `value`. however it should get updated everytime I run a loop `Clock.schedule_interval(RootWidget.update, 1.0/1.0)`

here is the python, simplified so its basically just the time, which is also printed just to see if it is actually working.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
import time

class RootWidget(FloatLayout):


    def update(self, *args):
        value = time.time()
        print value
        self.ids.value_label.text = str(value)


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.size = (800, 480)
        r = RootWidget()
        Clock.schedule_interval(r.update, 1)
        print 'build running'
        return r

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

the kv file looks as such:

```
<RootWidget>:

Label:
    id: value_label
    text:
    y: 20.0
    x: 0.0
    width: 100.0
    italic: False
    height: 50.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clock.schedule_interval(RootWidget.update, 1.0/1.0)
```

You need to schedule the update method of an *instance*, not the class itself.

For instance:

```
r = RootWidget()
Clock.schedule_interval(r.update, 1)
return r
```

The clock will pass some arguments by default, so you should also declare the update method to accept these. If you don't want to use them then you can just do:

```
def update(self, *args):
    ...
```

Comment: thank you! However I still get following error: `self.value_label.text = str(value)
 AttributeError: 'RootWidget' object has no attribute 'value_label'`

Comment: That's because indeed that attribute doesn't exist. You can access the label by id with self.ids.value_label

Comment: thank you very much! I changed it to `self.ids.value_label.text = str(value)` which results in following AttributeError: `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`